# How to log sql parameter values on mybatis

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I use mybatis 3.5.6 and mybatis-spring 2.0.0. I use log4j2 to log sql statements. I am able to write logs to a file but couldnt make it print sql parameter values instead of ?. i have tried setting level="DEBUG", level="TRACE", level="debug", level="trace". i saw the difference when i set different values but each time sql parameters are masked and ? s are shown in the log.

Is it possible to make it print parameter values in sql queries instead of printing them in anotler line? it would be better to understand where each parameter is

here is the logger i use;

```
    <AsyncLogger name="com.service.Mapper" level="DEBUG" additivity="false"
        includeLocation="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="MYBATIS" />
    </AsyncLogger>
```

com.service.Mapper is an xml mapper

Comment: The statement with placeholders`?` is output to the line starts with `==>  Preparing:`. The parameters are output to the line starts with `==> Parameters:`.

Comment: yes later i noticed

Comment: The `DEBUG` level prints the SQL statement, while the `TRACE` level includes the parameter values as well.

Comment: @yılmaz MyBatis itself does not support inlining parameters in log output. If your goal is to execute the SQL in another tool, MyBatipse (=Eclipse plugin)'s [smart-copy](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatipse#miscellaneous) might come in handy. Alternatively, you can use some external tool like [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy). BTW, parameter values are printed in `DEBUG` level. `TRACE` level enables result value logging.